# Download SVG EDIT for using it in mediawiki

Tags: 12.04, installation, svg, mediawiki

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server with mediawiki 1.21 (newest stable) version on it.
Now I need this extension [svgedit extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSVGEdit) , I configurated my LocalSettings.php and  put all required files in the dir `extension/SVGEdit` .
Now I am stuck at this point :
[Configuration](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSVGEdit#Configuration)  , I want to host the SVG-Editor on my own server and now I need the programm, but I can't find the needed one. Do I understand it correctly, that I have to install the SVGEdit then in `extensions/SVGEdit/svg-edit`?

Any help is upvoted immediately! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Download SVGedit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/downloads/list) and place it (unziped) in `extensions/SVGEdit/svg-edit`
2. Open LocalSettings.php (with some terminal editor such as vim or nano) and add **or** change the following:

   i. `require_once("$IP/extensions/SVGEdit/SVGEdit.php");`

   ii. `$wgFileExtensions[] = 'svg';`

   iii.  `$wgAllowTitlesInSVG = true;`

   iv. `$wgSVGConverter = 'ImageMagick';`
3. In terminal issue the following to install ImageMagick:

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
4. Finally try first without setting the `$wgSVGEditEditor` setting

Comment: that's what I did so far, besides downloading the SVGEDIt, did you find a link to download it ?  I have imagemagick installed but not on that path. so I used $wgSVGConverterPath ='/usr/lib/mime/packages/imagemagick';   not sure if this is the right path as well :(

Comment: Regarding image magic if it is installed with apt then follow the answer. As for download link see the update in my answer.

Comment: installed everything and i don't have any errors, so it should be fine. But still i can't see any difference. No buttons to edit my pictures. hhmmm

Comment: I assume you have downloaded the svg-edit-2.6.zip file and not the one of the browser extensions. After unzipping it you will probably have `extensions/SVGEdit/svg-edit/svg-edit-2.6` try to mv the contents of svg-edit-2.6 on directory up to `extensions/SVGEdit/svg-edit/`. Lastly check if the directory is accessible by the web server.

Comment: yes I downloaded the 2.6 version not the extension for firefox and i put it in the right directory ;)  I have an idea. give me some minutes ;)